# Async method call in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, async-await

I have @Html.Translate() extension method, which returns translated string. Translations are stored in database, so I want to make async call to database from helper method. 
Can I make async method calls from razor view? 
Is here some workaround to call async methods in razor view?

Comment: Can some explain what OP meant by 'async calls from razor view'? aren't these ajax calls?

Comment: No, this question is about async/await C#. Like await HttpClient.PostAsync

Comment: Have you considered creating a model of your view (a view model) with the already translated strings. On the controller you can have async code.

Comment: Could just call the method from a view like this: `var car = MyFactory.MakeCar().Result;` for a signature of the method being: `async Task<Car> MakeCar()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Async method calls from razor view are supported (or will be supported) only in ASP.NET vNext (MVC 6).

If you are using MVC 5 version and eralier, the simplest solution to your problem would be adding a property to your view model and filling it with async call to db. So when your view is rendered all the data will already be in the model and ready for use.

**P.S** also calling a database from view sounds a little fishy. May be you should review this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for answer, looks like I need to use MVC6. My task is to implement @Html.Translate(key) html helper. Do you suggest to fetch all strings in controller and pass it to view through model? But that is realy unhandy then just call @Html.Translate("key")