# Async call from HTML helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am making an simple webclient async call from HTML Helper. Why do I get this exception on running this code.

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())                {
   webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
   webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
   webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   string orderString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orders);
   string result = webClient.UploadStringAsync(createOrderURI, orderString);
```

exception

> System.InvalidOperationException An asynchronous operation cannot be
>   started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started
>   within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in
>   the Page lifecycle

I do not want to get into moving controller to async etc as I am using Umbraco teacommerce for orders. And this call is to external api when the order was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "[Async method call in Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436756/async-method-call-in-razor-view)" async methoc calls are not supported in ASP.NET MVC but in ASP.NET Core MVC.

So async calls in the View itsself or a HTML Helper, which calls are executed in the same context,  is not possible in your case. The Razor engine catches these attempts and the quoted exception is thrown.

In order to follow the MVC pattern I suggest to reevaluate the idea to put this logic into the controller in an async action method and put the data into the model of the view.

Comment: Thanks. Right, gotta bite the bullet. Will have to tap-in controllers of teacommerce to see what I can do.